# How to use group By with if else condition query builder in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-query-builder

i am new in laravel . can anyone tell me , how to use groupBy with if else condition .
i have developed query and run in phpmyadmin directly , displaying result fine .

Below the query

```
**SELECT * FROM toolboxes GROUP BY IF(check_group!='0',check_group, id)**
```

But , when i passed groupBy wtih laravel query builder, not supporting this format.

```
 $toolboxs = Toolbox::get()->sortByDesc('created_at')->groupBy(IF(check_group!='0',check_group, id))
        ->map(function ($toolboxs) {
            return [
                'id' => $toolboxs->id,
                'groupId' => $toolboxs->check_group,
                'title' => $toolboxs->title,
                'brief' => $toolboxs->brief,
                'description' => $toolboxs->description,
            ];
        });

$query = DB::table('toolboxes')
       ->select(DB::raw("id,check_group,title,brief,description"))
       ->groupBy(if(check_group!='0',check_group, id))
        ->toSql();
```

**I have tried these syntax , but not working . please help me :)**